# LyX break numbered equation to multiple pages

Tags: lyx

I have a question using the LyX.

I first do: `Insert` -> `math` -> `numbered formula`,
then `Insert` -> `math` -> `aligned environment`

but `\allowdisplaybreaks` does not work.

How can I break numbered equation into different pages?

Comment: Specifically, please post a minimal example:  https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Answer (score 2):

With what you're doing, you end up with LaTeX code for your equation similar to

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  aligned &= math
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

And that is the problem, you can't have page breaks inside an `equation` environment, even if it contains an `aligned`.

Instead what you must use is an `align` environment. Instead of the "Numbered formula", choose Insert --> Math --> AMS align. Then right click in the formula, and choose "Number whole formula" (shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>. With that you end up with code like

```
\begin{align}
  aligned &= math
\end{align}
```

and page breaking between the lines of this one will work, when `\allowdisplaybreaks` is in effect.

Of course, this will make each line numbered, instead of having a single number for the entire block.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply Torbjørn T. 
There is not any way to give only one number to the entire block?

Comment: @user145703 Forgot to mention something about that. You can disable numbering for individual lines by right clicking in the equation. I don't have any better ideas.

Comment: I did this. 
Insert --> Math --> AMS align. Then type equations. Since I add \allowdisplaybreaks in the Setting --> LaTex preamble, now I can see that the equation is shown in different pages. But there is not any equation number at the end of every line, which is different from what you said. And now in the AMS align, Insert -> math -> numbered formula cannot be selected any more.

Comment: @user145703 Oops, sorry, it's unnumbered by default. Right click in the align and choose "Number whole formula".

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes. I tried this. 
Insert --> Math -->numbered formula. The right click, and select AMS environment -->AMS align environment. In this case, \allowdisplaybreaks works.